# Is there a way of cleaning a node_modules directory leaving only the required dependent files?

Tags: node.js, deployment, npm, npm-publish

Installing and managing packages using npm is great! What I don't find so great is the mess it can leave.

I've started using npm for both client and node dependency management and I've noticed lots of different *arrangements* for the various packages I rely on. Some have `lib` folders, some have `src` folders, some `dist`, some `docs`, some `examples` Etc.
I understand that this is because generally these packages come directly from source.

My question is:

Is there a way of identifying or even automating the removal of any unneeded files, for deployment to production? 
I'm thinking: removal of any readme.md (easy enough I guess) or example files (probably easy enough).

Ideally I'd like to be able to calculate exactly what the dependency tree looks like from my entry point and delete unneeded / unused files ... This is obviously a lot harder for client packages that rely on images or fonts or HTML for example.

**EDIT:**

As pointed out by Alexander Mac (below) A good strategy for front-end dep's is to include client dependencies as dev-dependencies and build. So my question is only related to nodejs apps.

Comment: You shouldn't deploy backend dependencies on production? You should install them with `npm i --production`. What about frontend dependencies, you can build them locally (with task runner such as gulp) and push only bundles to the server.

Comment: - Alexander Mac fair point about the front end dependencies. Installing front end dependencies as dev dependencies and building makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I might suggest building your code (and deps) into one bundle with [rollup.js](http://rollupjs.org) or [webpack2](http://www.2ality.com/2015/12/webpack-tree-shaking.html).

These module loaders leverage [tree-shaking](https://medium.com/@Rich_Harris/tree-shaking-versus-dead-code-elimination-d3765df85c80#.lz69ukz81) approach to include only the code that is actually used.

Comment: GREAT! I'm using Webpack on the client - I'll take a look and see if this explains what I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can run: `npm prune` which will remove modules from ./node_modules not specified as dependencies in packages.json.

`npm dedupe` will remove duplicate dependencies by pulling equivalent modules up to the root ./node_modules/. I don't know how useful this is though. I did it and then realised there were a whole bunch of modules I was using indirectly which I could also use directly, so there's that.

A surefire way of doing this is also:

`rm -rf ./node_modules ./bower_components
npm install`

It's good practice to do a clean build before release to production anyway.

Also, I use `sinopia` to cache modules locally, which relieves network traffic, so these re-installs are a bit less time intensive.